# Phaser3: Vercel deploy fail (updated)

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose, vite, phaser-framework

I using Vite + React + Typescript, and use Vercel for deployment. In my localhost `build` or `preview` are working fine.

[image]

```
11:57:49.482 error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'Phaser
11:57:49.482   The file is in the program because:
11:57:49.483     Entry point of type library 'Phaser' specified in compileroptions
11:57:49.500   ELIFECYCLE Command failed with exit code 2.
11:57:49.526 Error: Command "pnpm run build" exited with 1
11:57:50.217 Deployment completed
11:57:49.841 BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "pnpm run build" exited with 1
```

`ts.config.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext","es6", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"],
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types","./node_modules/phaser/types"],
    "types": ["Phaser"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "files": ["./node_modules/phaser/types/phaser.d.ts"],
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

**Now I trying to run on local using docker, but still facing same issue**

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
```

`Dockerfile`

```
# Base image
FROM node:16-alpine

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and pnpm-lock.yaml to the container
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install -g pnpm && pnpm install

# Copy the rest of the application files to the container
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN pnpm run build

# Expose the port
EXPOSE 3000
# Start the application
CMD ["pnpm", "run", "preview"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue that I have to remove `"types": ["Phaser"],` in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext","es6", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"],
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/phaser/types","./node_modules/@types"],
    // "types": ["Phaser"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "files": ["./node_modules/phaser/types/phaser.d.ts"],
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

Comment: Good catch, well done.

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
```

That seems suspect: In your `docker-compose.yml` file, you're mounting the current directory to `/app` and also mounting `/app/node_modules` to a Docker volume.
That could be causing issues with how Docker is finding your `node_modules` directory and, consequently, the `Phaser` types.

Remove the volume and, in your Dockerfile, create a fresh `node_modules` directory inside the container, which should include the `Phaser` types: TypeScript should then be able to find them.

```
# Base image
FROM node:16-alpine

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and pnpm-lock.yaml to the container
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install -g pnpm && pnpm install

# Remove and reinstall node_modules
RUN rm -rf node_modules && pnpm install

# Copy the rest of the application files to the container
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN pnpm run build

# Expose the port
EXPOSE 3000
# Start the application
CMD ["pnpm", "run", "preview"]
```

If the problem persists, check whether the `node_modules/phaser/types` directory actually exists inside your Docker container.

```
RUN ls -la node_modules/phaser/types
```

The content of that directory should include `phaser.d.ts`.